# what is the most reasonable way apply webpack to a full-stack node app?

Tags: express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i've been studying up on webpack for a couple of weeks now, and i've seen many examples of front end setups, and probably just [this one setup for a backend](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I).

i'm trying to setup a react app with a node back-end (e.g. express, koa, hapi, etc) where i would need at least one transpilation step for the back-end (e.g. babel, coffeescript, etc), and i think it would be nice to use webpack there for consistency vs adding another build mechanism to the mix (e.g. gulp, grunt, etc).

it would also be great if i could make changes to the backend and have the server restart automatically (watch style).

i'm wondering if the best way to do that is to basically have two distinct project setups with their own package.json and webpack.config files. maybe nest the back-end one under a `server` folder in the top level project folder, and use one or more script directives in the top level package.json file to control the two.

i guess i might have to proxy one server to the other to avoid CORS issues as well.

looking for any guidance from those more webpack battle tested than i for a decent setup.

regards,
tony.

Comment: What's wrong with the server-side webpack example mentioned in the article you linked? (https://github.com/jlongster/backend-with-webpack)

Comment: i don't think anything, do you think it's best to manage the front and back as basically distinct projects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easiest way is to split this into two tasks: a build step that outputs to a folder (e.g. 'server'), then watch the output folder for changes and restart server task.

#### 1. Build task

This can be in the same webpack.config as client building code - you can export an array and webpack will watch all of them.
Example webpack.config.js (top half is for server)

```
module.exports = [
{
  name: 'server code, output to ./server',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: './server/index.js'
  },
  target: 'node'
},
{
  name: 'client side, output to ./public',
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    filename: './public/app.js'
  }
}
];
```

#### 2.Watch Step

For the watch step, [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) monitor changes and restart. Otherwise you could add a watch task to your server.js manually using something like [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) or [node-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-watch).

Comment: thanks @psimyn your response above contains several pointers i wasn't aware of, i also appreciate the reference you left me in gitter re: [isomorphic-flux-boilerplate](https://github.com/iam4x/isomorphic-flux-boilerplate) which looks to be an impressive and sophisticated setup (i'll have to grow into that one). thx!

Comment: this doesn't work when you try using it with express.  More specifically it doesn't resolve the location for node_modules when using a loader (ie. babel-loader).