# How to use Express to serve a frontend compiled by Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the following Express app which serves static files, specifically `public/index.html`.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening @ http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**public/index.html**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>

        <script>
            // possibly make API calls to http://localhost:8000
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

This HTML file requires a script located at `./dist/bundle.js`.

The bundle is compiled using Webpack, which has this configuration:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js"] },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist/"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname,
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()]
    }
};
```

As you can see in `output.path`, the bundle's compiled output should go into `public/dist` which is inside the static file directory served by Express. That way, `index.html` can access it.

Now the problem is, my development workflow is incredibly inefficient.

1. `webpack --mode development` to write the latest `bundle.js` into `public/dist`
2. `node server.js` to re-run the server (in case there were any server-side changes)

If I were using `webpack-dev-server` alone without my own backend, I would get all the nice benefits of hot reloading, HMR, etc, and I don't have to worry about recompiling.

I know I can run `webpack-dev-server` and `server.js` concurrently on two different ports, but `index.html` would be served from `server.js` and wouldn't be able to access the in memory `dist/bundle.js` served by the webpack dev server.

Is there a way to serve a Webpack-compiled frontend from an Express server and still get all the nice benefits of using Webpack-dev-server, specifically hot reloading?

Thanks!

Comment: #2 can be solved with nodemon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686531/what-is-the-most-reasonable-way-apply-webpack-to-a-full-stack-node-app does this help?